# How many possible meanings does " inclusion" have?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I want to know how many possible meaning does " inclusion" have in this sentence, I cant get its meaning. " I am all for inclusion. but that part of the country? those are not my people."

Comment: Just TBC it's referring to an anti-racist view, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Inclusion* here means *including all people* or possibly *including all of those people*.  The person speaking is essentially expressing a prejudice ("those are not my people") while attempting to come across as unprejudiced ("I am all for inclusion").
It's a nice example of how English can be used to express unpleasant sentiments in disguise :)